# 500 internal server error. other php websites running well. without any problem

Tags: magento, wamp

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: can any one help me out

Comment: Since other sites are working, look at the file/folder permissions (644/755). If it is an Apache take a look at .htaccess file... I would start looking permissions.

Comment: http://localhost/magento/admin_p4c5ti/admin/index/index/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.... after this nothing showing on web page only black screen appearing..magento admin page is just black screen